# How to look for a specific string using the LIKE command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `WHERE` statement in a SQL stored procedure that I am checking against a table which stores data as XML:

```
WHERE
(
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
OR
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty2/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
OR
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty3/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
OR
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty4/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
OR
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty5/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
OR
    CAST ([content_html] AS XML).value('(/root/Physicians/specialty6/a/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') LIKE '%' + @strService + '%'
)
```

`strService` is sent in from the front end to my code-behind which runs the stored procedure.

Each of the `OR` statement refers to each textbox in the XML document.

For example, If I send `@strService` = `Urology` the query searches for `Urology`, and `Neurology`, because `Urology` is also in `Neurology`

How can I check to see if content is equal to @strService OR if the word exists somewhere within content with non-letters around it OR if it's at the very beginning or very end of content with a non-letter either following or preceding respectively.

Here is an example:

I have the following entries:

```
Pediatric Urology
Urology
Neurology
```

I have the following `LIKE` statement:

`LIKE 'Urology'` = `only Urology is displayed`

`LIKE '% Urology` = `nothing is displayed`

`LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]Urology'` = `only Pediatric Urology is displayed`

I would like to show `Pediatric Urology` and `Urology` in this case.

Pretty much as long as the word exist with a space in front of it, I would like to show.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...?

Comment: @Barranka SQL Server

Comment: `LIKE '% Urology` is displaying nothing because it is missing the closing single quote. Also, you need to `OR` these statements (`CONTENT LIKE 'Urology' OR CONTENT LIKE '% Urology' OR CONTENT LIKE 'Urology %'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
CONTENT LIKE @strService 
OR CONTENT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]' + @strService + '[^a-zA-Z]%' 
OR CONTENT LIKE @strService + '[^a-zA-Z]%'
OR CONTENT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]' + @strService
```

Heres an explanation:

```
 CONTENT LIKE @strService
```

will check for equality

```
 CONTENT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]' + @strService + '[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

will check for the case where the word exists somewhere within content with non-letters around it

```
 CONTENT LIKE @strService + '[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

will check for the case where the word exists at the very beginning of content with a non-letter following

```
 CONTENT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]' + @strService
```

will check for the case where the word exists at the very end of content with a non-letter preceding.

If you'd like to exclude numbers from the set of possible adjacent letters, use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` in place of `[^a-zA-Z]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: CONTENT LIKE @strService is good and how can I add an OR statemement to check if there is a space before Urology? For  example, If I search for Urology, Urology and Pediatric Urology should come up.

Comment: The [^a-zA-Z] regex should include spaces.

Comment: How about ONLY include space?

Comment: Then replace "[^a-zA-Z]" with " " (space character).

Comment: So `LIKE ' Urology'`?

Comment: If you want to see if CONTENT includes " Urology" at the end of it, do `CONTENT LIKE '% Urology'`. You need the wildcard (%) to match letters before the space.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated my question with the issue I am having. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation of the string depends on the type of RDBMS you are using
For eg:

> Oracle and Postgrasql uses "||"
>   While SQL-server uses "+"

And the use of correct wild character will help you to find what you are looking for.

Comment: I am using SQL Server.